# Postgresql- Is possible to create a table from a view in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, database-connection

I have been asked to make a system to handle SQL server data, and put them in postgresql, but the only thing I have on is a view, I do not have permissions or anything else in SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these limited permissions, you can do a `SELECT *` from the view in SQL server, save the output to a CSV and import it into PostgreSQL either with:

- The native `COPY` command (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)
- A dedicated import tool like http://pgloader.io/howto/csv.html